# $A,N$ are $n \times n$ complex matrices with $N$ normal has $AN^*=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw a video solving a question using example, but I don't understand how its considered sufficient as a general proof.

The question:
Assume $A,N$ are $n \times n$ complex matrices, $N$ is a normal matrix and $AN=0$. Prove that $AN^*=0$.

The proof by example was:
Let take $V$ as the space of complex $n \times n$  matrices with the standard inner product and he shows that $(AN^*,AN^*)=0$  which proves that $AN^*=0$

How is this example enough to prove general claim?

Comment: How is this "proof by example"?

Comment: you take spesific space with  standard inner product, its kind of example

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question is unclear. What you write does not show an example, it seems to be the outline of a proof. If you [edit] the question to show us just what the video says (not a link to the video) we may be able to help. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $x=0$ if and only if $\langle x,x \rangle =0$ in every inner product space. So this is not a special case.

Comment: A specific space and a specific inner product are used in the proof.  That's not "[proof by example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_example)".  Proof by example would be if you took a particular $A$ and $N$, or maybe a particular $n$.

Comment: @EthanBolker it's exactly the question and the proof only without the way.

Comment: @RobertIsrael ok, so while using specific space and specific inner product how is it still considered general proof?

Comment: @CyclotomicField right, but how using  spesific space and inner product to proof general claim is consider enough? It feels more like an example to me than a general proof. How the proof so obvious to you guys, what am I missing?

Comment: @LinearBrain The question regards a statement about matrices $A$ and $N$. The truth of this statement is unaffected by the decision of the proof-writer to define an inner product over $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann So is it enough to proof like that? i just dont understand why its enough

Comment: @LinearBrain Why do you think that it is **not** enough? We started with the given information ($A$ and $N$ are complex matrices, $N$ is normal, $AN = 0$) and we have arrived at the conclusion (that $AN^* = 0$). What is it about the steps that might make the argument fail to apply?

Comment: @LinearBrain We defined a "specific inner product" that is applicable no matter which matrices $A$ and $N$ we were given

Comment: my sense is OP (1) needs to carefully write out the definition of "normal matrix" and (2)  would understand the official argument better if no mention of "standard inner product" was made, but instead $B:=AN^*$ and the official solution said we are going to show this is zero by looking at the sum of [modulus] squares , i.e. show $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \vert b_{i,j}\vert^2 =0$

Answer (score 1):

$\langle AN^*,AN^*\rangle=tr((AN^*)^*AN^*)=tr(NA^*AN^*)=tr(A^*AN^*N)=tr(A^*ANN^*)=0\Rightarrow AN^*=0$.

Comment: This doesn't address the question that this post is about, which is "How is this example enough to prove general claim?"